# SQLite simple insert based on a field value

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-insert

A should be simple problem in SQL (SQLite).

I have a table `tab` like this

```
 id     |   amount  |  descr 
 ---------------------------
 bolt   |        8  |  "ok"
 screw  |       20  |  "ok"
 screw  |        1  |  "ok"
```

For each distinct value of `id` I wish to insert a new row with the corresponding max `amount` incremented by 1 and having the `description` "incremented".

```
 id     |   amount  |  descr 
 ---------------------------
 bolt   |        8  |  "ok"
 bolt   |        9  |  "incremented"
 screw  |       20  |  "ok"
 screw  |        1  |  "ok"
 screw  |       21  |  "incremented"
```

This is my "try" (so wrong that it would probably be better to leave it out)

```
INSERT INTO tab VALUES (
    myid, 
    SELECT 1 + MAX(amount) FROM tab WHERE tab.id = myid,
    "incremented" )
WHERE myid = tab.id -- pretends to "foreach" id in tab
```

Seems like a simple problem but Im afraid Im too newbie (besides plain old thick) on SQL (SQLite) to solve it without having to resorting to "reading the book":-O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pretty close.  You want an aggregation query:

```
insert into tab (myid, amount, descr)
    select myid, max(amount) + 1, 'incremented'
    from tab
    group by myid;
```